# Getting a unique array from a service in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a service that contains information about members. One of the variables here is the team string.

In my component, I call the service method to put the information in a variable before showing it in the component.

I would like to fill the variable "teams" in my component with an unique list of teams in the service. This should take into account writing (so I would use toUpperCase()).

My service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserinfoService
{
    //methods or services
    getMembers()
    {
        return [
            {
                imageUrl: "../assets/images/filler.jpg",
                firstName: "filler",
                lastName: "filler",
                team: "TEAM A",
                number: "+123456798",
                bio: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...",
                isActive: true
            },
            {
                imageUrl: "../assets/images/filler.jpg",
                firstName: "filler",
                lastName: "filler",
                team: "TEam A",
                number: "+123456798",
                bio: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...",
                isActive: false
            },
            {
                imageUrl: "../assets/images/filler.jpg",
                firstName: "filler",
                lastName: "filler",
                team: "TEAM B",
                number: "+123456798",
                bio: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...",
                isActive: true
            },
        ];
    }
    //constructor
    constructor()
    {
    }
}
```

my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserinfoService } from '../services/userinfo.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-teammembers',
  templateUrl: './teammembers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teammembers.component.css']
})
export class TeammembersComponent implements OnInit
{
    //props
    teammembers: any[];
    teams:any[];

    constructor(userinfoService: UserinfoService)
    {
        //getData
        this.teammembers = userinfoService.getMembers();
    }            

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.teams = uniq(this.teammembers.map(member => member.team))`. You can write `uniq` yourself, or use a library.

Comment: `[...new Set(this.teammembers.map(m => m.team))]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With ES6, you can achieve this in one line. Below is an example:

> ```
> this.teams = this.teammembers
>                  .map(item => item.team)
>                  .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
> ```

Comment: This is great. Works perfectly. Would you care to explain to me how it actually works? Thank you :)

Comment: @user3110254 Here you can find the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/map-method-array-javascript

Comment: that sounds good!